Proposition 3.2. of Bertsekas' paper about Lagrange multipliers
This is a problem about the proposition 3.2 of Bertsekas' paper below.
Bertsekas D P, Ozdaglar A E. Pseudonormality and a Lagrange multiplier theory for constrained optimization[J]. Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications, 2002, 114: 287-343.
This is an accessible link
https://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Pseudonormality.pdf
The original problem form is in the following form:
\begin{equation}\begin{array}{ll}\min&f(x),\\\\\mathrm{s.t.}&x\in C,\end{array}\end{equation}
The constraint set $C$ is as below:
\begin{equation}C=X\cap\{x|h_1(x)=0,\ldots,h_m(x)=0\}\\\cap\{x|g_1(x)\leq0,\ldots,g_r(x)\leq0\}.\end{equation}
where $f, h_i, i=1\ldots m, g_j, j=1\ldots r$ are all smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty closed set.
In the section 3 of this paper, authors introduced quasinormality and pseudonormality to conclude several constraint qualifications. I refer the definitions of these two concepts to the beginning of the section 3. You can click the link to see and I will not mention the details here for the whole conciseness.
Then in the proposition 3.2, authors assumed the normal cone $N_X(x^*)$ is convex and want to prove that quasinormality is equivalent with a weaker pseudonormality which combines the condition $(\mathrm{i})-(\mathrm{iii})$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}&(\mathrm{i})\quad-\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_i\nabla h_i(x^*)+\sum_{j=1}^r\mu_j\nabla g_j(x^*)\right]\in N_X(x^*).\\&(\mathrm{ii})\quad\mu_j\geq0,\quad\text{for all }j=1,\ldots,r.\\&(\mathrm{iii})\quad\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m\mathrm{~and~}\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_r\text{ are not all equal to }0.\end{aligned}\end{equation}
with the property below
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(\mathrm{iv'})& \{x^k\}\text{ converges to }x^*\mathrm{~and,~for~all~}k,\lambda_ih_i(x^k)\geq0\mathrm{~for~all~}i, \\
&\mu_{j}g_{j}(x^{k})\geq0 \mathrm{~for~all~} j, \mathrm{~and} \\
&\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\lambda_{i}h_{i}(x^{k})+\sum_{j = 1}^{r}\mu_{j}g_{j}(x^{k})>0.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
In the proof, the paper simplified the problem with only inequalities constraints and assumed that they are all active. Then they rewrote the weaker pseudonormality as
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \mathrm{(i)}\quad-\biggl[\sum_{j = 1}^{r}\mu_{j}\nabla g_{j}(x^{*})\biggr] \in N_{X}(x^{*}). \\
& \mathrm{(ii)}\quad\mu_{j}\geq0,\quad\mathrm{for~all~}j=1,\ldots,r. \\
&\text{(iii})\quad\{x^k\}\text{ converges to }x^*\text{ and for all }k,g_j(x^k)\geq0\text{ for all }j,\text{ and} \\
&\sum_{j=1}^r\mu_jg_j(x^k)>0.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
My question is: How to derive the argument below from the property above? Why must we have $g_j(x^k)\geq0$ for all $j$? Could it be possible that $g_j(x^k)<0$ for some $j$ with corresponding $\mu_j=0$?
Thank you for any help.

Simplify your thoughts. If this would be negative the global property of convexity is violated. This works only in the situation is which the simple model of convexity that is usually present in the idea spectra of students is valid in the tighter dimensions. Others on that topic enter into the work with the abstract proving that is not very sorrowful, just verification or falsification. Present higher dimensional problems that can be simplified.

@SteffenJaeschke this makes not much sense. These functions are not assumed to be convex.

The property $g_j(x^k) \ge 0$ would follow if $\mu_j>0$. Maybe the authors have this kind of strict complementarity somewhere assumed/mentioned/etc.

Might help to describe the assumptions, etc, for those who do not have JOTA access.

@copper.hat Thank you for the advice, I'll describe some assumptions and give an accessible link.

@SteffenJaeschke Thank you but functions are not convex. I edited the problem and made the describe clearer.

@daw That's the point. But there are no assumptions about this and we cannot discard the constriants with zero multiplier. Thank you for your help.

I post some of my new findings here.
I still don't know why that property makes sense and I think it's probably wrong, but this won't affect the whole conclusion. We can just use the original property as $(\mathrm{iv}')$,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}&\{x^{k}\} \mathrm{~converges~to~}x^{*} \mathrm{and~for~all~}k,\mu_jg_{j}(x^{k})\geq0 \mathrm{~for~all~}j, \mathrm{and}\sum_{j = 1}^{r}\mu_{j}g_{j}(x^{k})>0.\end{aligned}\end{equation}
The proof of the proposition uses this property at two places. At the first place, we want to find one inequality constraint which get strict inequality. Then from $\sum_{j = 1}^{r}\mu_{j}g_{j}(x^{k})>0$, we know there must be one $j$ with $g_{j}(x^{k})>0$. At the second place, we just need $g_{j}(x^{k})>0$ is satisfied for all $j$ with the multiplier $\mu_{\bar{m}_j}>0$. So $\mu_jg_{j}(x^{k})\geq0 \mathrm{~for~all~}j$ is enough to derive this. So we don't need such strong argument.
Thanks for any discussions and help.
